# How can you 干/乾 燒 lobster on an electric cooktop, in a residential apartment?

Tags: lobster

1. I don't know the English translation of 干燒/乾燒? Perhaps dry sear, or dry sizzle? I don't use "grill", because Cantonese restaurants confirmed to me that they don't use grills for this dish.
2. How can I replicate the following with frozen lobster meat, and [my Frigidaire electric cooktop](https://www.lowes.com/pl/Frigidaire--Electric-cooktops-Cooktops-Appliances/4294715799?refinement=4294965783)? I have no oven.

[image: electric cooktop]

My priority is flavor and taste! I don't care about looks or presentation, or char or grill marks.

[Top](https://omeirestaurant.ca/product/emeimeizhiganshaoshuanglongxia/), [Middle from TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.ca/Restaurant_Review-g181740-d976985-Reviews-Omei_Restaurant-Richmond_Hill_Ontario.html#photos;aggregationId=101&albumid=101&filter=7&ff=191613893), [Bottom from Yelp](https://www.yelp.ca/biz_photos/omei-restaurant-richmond-hill?select=f1WhcYJxUdM6LmHBZmjPsg).

[image: top lobster example]

[image: middle lobster example]

[image: bottom lobster example]

Answer (score 28):

Short answer: you can't, but probably not for the reason you think.

Longer answer: the phrase you're quoting above, 干燒/乾燒, means "dry-fried", which generally (and somewhat paridoxically) refers to [putting food through a brief and very hot shallow fry](https://www.seriouseats.com/wok-skills-102-how-to-dry-fry-in-a-wok) before the finishing stir-fry.  This technique is [absolutely doable at home](https://blog.themalamarket.com/chongqing-lobster-chongqing-long-xia/), even on an electric burner as long as you have a good flat-bottomed wok.

So what's the problem?  It's that you're using "frozen lobster meat".  Thawed lobster meat, with no shells, is already dehydrated and tough due to the freeze-and-thaw process.  If you "dry-fry" that meat, it's going to have the texture of vulcanized rubber or even wood.

So, my advice to you is either get a fresh whole lobster, or at least frozen shell-on tails, if you want to try making dry-fried lobster.  Or, if you need to use up that bag of frozen lobster meat, [batter and deep-fry it instead](https://justcook.butcherbox.com/lobster-tempura/).

Comment: **Isn't there a contradiction in your answer? If *"Thawed lobster meat, with no shells, is already dehydrated and tough due to the freeze-and-thaw process"*, then why would *"frozen shell-on tails"* work? Why aren't *"frozen shell-on tails"* likewise *"dehydrated and tough due to the freeze-and-thaw process"*? If I *"dry-fry" "frozen shell-on tails"*, then won't these tails likewise *"have the texture of vulcanized rubber or even wood"?* Please distinguish "thawed lobster meat, with no shells" from "frozen shell-on tails"**?

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me.  One has a shell on, the other doesn't.  For any shellfish, freezing with the shell on retains moisture.